# How to select entries that are back to back?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How would I select `c_user_id` who have made back to back entries in a SQL Server 2008 database ?

Preferably people who have made more than 3 back to back entries like `pras.chla@gmail.com` below (sorting by `c_id desc` and `c_id` is an identity column)

```
c_id    c_user_id             c_entry
1427    xermadr.asdf@me.com   155575
1426    pras.chla@gmail.com   155829
1425    pras.chla@gmail.com   155826
1424    pras.chla@gmail.com   155828
1423    pras.chla@gmail.com   155830
1422    sdfe.qqol@gmail.com   155559
```

thanks again ?

Comment: Can you define *back to back* more clearly? If you mean contiguous, order by what column?

Comment: What are you using to define back to back entries?  c_id?  C_entry?

Comment: How do you define "back to back"?  That would entirely change based on the sorting used in the query.  And it's probably not a good idea to use the default sort for anything important, since there's no guarantee that it'll be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH someUserTableWithOrderNumber as
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER ( )  OVER (order by c_id) OrderNumber, 
    c_id, 
    c_user_id, 
    c_entry 
FROM someUserTable
)
SELECT DISTINCT a.c_user_id
FROM someUserTableWithOrderNumber a
JOIN someUserTableWithOrderNumber b on a.OrderNumber = b.OrderNumber + 1 AND a.c_user_id = b.c_user_id 
JOIN someUserTableWithOrderNumber c on b.OrderNumber = c.OrderNumber + 1 AND b.c_user_id = c.c_user_id 
JOIN someUserTableWithOrderNumber d on c.OrderNumber = d.OrderNumber + 1 AND c.c_user_id = d.c_user_id
```

Comment: You're assuming that ids are guaranteed sequential. This won't be the case unless the OP has rolled their own identity scheme.

Comment: For my education: can I ask what the difference was from your first sql post and second question why two JOIN statements...what does the second do for you ???  Many thanks.

Comment: It handles gaps in the c_id. Like if you deleted a record or if your identity wasn't the standard (1,1).

Comment: The two joins will only match if the next record in the set matches userid. You do this twice plus the original gets you three in a row.

Comment: Just updated, missed that it had to be greater than three, but not equal to three.

Comment: "How about that"? Looks about three times as expensive as the `ROW_NUMBER` one in my answer and not as extensible if the number to consider changes but +1

Comment: @JTC Many Thanks...I have tested both answers and they both work. I've maked your correct because you were first but can you (or anyone) tell me what the difference between answers are ...if any ??? (and if anyone really feels like schooling a noob what the OVER operator does ??) thanks again.

Comment: @AhabLives - Take a look at the downloadable chapter 5 [linked to on this page](http://www.manning.com/nielsen/)

Comment: Part of the Row_Number syntax http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx
PS, you can use partition by with it to get a group by feel to your row_number. Is very useful and versatile.

Answer (score 4):

One way

```
SELECT DISTINCT c_user_id
FROM   tab t1
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT 1 AS C
                    FROM   (SELECT TOP 2 *
                            FROM   tab t2
                            WHERE  t2.c_id < t1.c_id
                            ORDER  BY t2.c_id DESC) T 
HAVING COUNT(c_user_id) = 2 AND COUNT(DISTINCT c_user_id) = 1 AND MIN(c_user_id) = t1.c_user_id) CA
```

Or another

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by c_id) -
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c_user_id order by c_id) AS Grp
FROM   tab t1
)
SELECT DISTINCT c_user_id
FROM T
GROUP BY c_user_id, Grp
HAVING COUNT(*) >=3
```

Comment: Wow. I was off in SQLFiddle coming up with a solution, and I come back and see the exact same thing from you. Oh well, for what it's worth: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5dc82/1. And P.S. This solution is much better than the accepted answer.